# How did Armin survive after being roasted and blasted away from the Colossal Titan?

Tags: attack-on-titan

In Season 3 Part 2 episode 17, We see Armin being roasted By toe Colossal Titan. After He "makes it quick for him" Armin's ODM gear falls off and he is launched, But how in the world did a nearly dead person survive a fall from 60+ meters(he was blasted up) I don't remember anyone saying that they saw him falling and saved him, and when we saw him again there were no broken bones. So how did he survive?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Good question. For me it‘s not really adding up either but I assume someone did catch him because falling from this height while already having your skin burnt off is almost impossible to survive. If he didn‘t fall from like 60 meters it would make a lot more sense. Also I assume that he really was half dead but maybe the most important organs somehow didn‘t take as much damage. It still looks weird next to Erwin who in comparison to Armin wasn‘t really injured. It was probably just convenience for the plot to be honest.

The characters of Attack On Titan in general can take lots of damage as well. I‘ve seen some discussion about how this really hot gas that comes from titans should damage the characters lungs when they inhale it in some scenes and it doesn‘t affect them at all.

Comment: Good answer, I really must be for the plot then, because if Armin could survive that Erwin should have lived

Comment: so sorry that I didnt check it sooner.

Answer (score 4):

You could survive that, but the likeliness is very low.

[Joan Murray survived a 14,500 feet drop and the only reason she survived was because she landed on a mound of fire ants which stung her so many times, adrenaline started to surge whiched is what caused her heart to stay beating](https://people.com/premium/beating-the-odds/).

There are also other factors that could play into this.

1. We see that in the panel where Armin is falling, [his anchors are still anchored to the Colossal Titan's teeth](https://official-complete-2.eorzea.us/manga/Shingeki-No-Kyojin/0082-030.png), which could've possibly slowed his descent. This is further supported in the [anime where he doesn't seem to be blasted away very hard.](https://youtu.be/Zxnk_ZzKmtE?t=184)
2. Characters have survived very similar feats, [such as Mikasa falling from a very large height without any injuries](https://youtu.be/g1jDgwysPcA?t=167). The existence of 3DMG just doesn't make any sense if we applied real life physics either. You can just chock it up to suspension of disbelief .
3. Plot Armor. Armin is a main character.

Comment: I liked this answer. I  also appreciated the links, but what was the adrenaline surge for Armin? Was it the plot armor? There are little to no soft places in shanganshina Given how heavily populated its landscape is with houses. Even if his hooks were still in the teeth and when he did he the ground, wouldn't he still get a lot of broken bones? My memory is a little fuzzy but I belive he landed on the house or he was found on the ground and picked up my a random shoulder?

Comment: He fell on a house, I'd say him burning could cause adrenaline. Honestly, you could chalk this up to plot armor but SNK makes no sense logically if we apply real world physics, (i.e 3DMG, characters jumping down from buildings, etc.)